# Minimal primes of $\Bbb C[w,x,y,z]/(w^2x,xy,yz^2)$ and their annihilators

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am examining the minimal primes of  $R=\Bbb C[w,x,y,z]/(w^2x,xy,yz^2)$, intersections between them, and the annihilators of each minimal prime.

If a minimal prime does not contain x, then it must contain both w and y. If it contains x, then it must contain one of y or z. So I think a complete set of minimal primes is given by $(w,y), (x,y)$ and $(x,z)$. (Good so far I hope?)

The problem is that I second-guess my judgement on conclusions about the annihilators and intersections.

Is it safe to conclude something about the generators of the intersections in terms of the generators of the ideals? The only thing I know for sure is that $(wx, yz)$ is nilpotent and hence contained in all three minimal primes.

I can also see $(wx)\subseteq ann(w,y)$,  $(w^2z^2)\subseteq ann(x,y)$ and $(yz)\subseteq ann(x,z)$, but I lose my train of thought trying to verify that they are equalities.

Any tips or theorems for clarifying how to think about these items are appreciated.

Comment: All your ideals are monomial, so you can work with bases very easily

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I think that's exactly the sort of thing I feel uncertain about that I'm looking for coaching on. Can you fill a comment with stuff everyone should know about handling monomial ideals (proofs left to me, of course)? I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez or better yet, fill a solution with whatever wisdom you can impart.

Comment: When I get a keyboard Ill do. Can you write down a basis of monomials of your ring? Such a basis will contain a basis of the three minimal primes (and you'll be able to read the intersections from that)

Comment: Ok, I will try this out on paper in the morning. Is the idea to move from R multiples of elements to $\Bbb C$ combinations of monomials? I think I can see how that would simplify things..

Comment: @rschwieb Are you switching to commutative algebra? ;)

Comment: @user26857 something like that :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(w^2x,xy,yz^2)=(\underline{w}^2,xy,yz^2)\cap(\underline{x},xy,yz^2)=(w^2,\underline{x},yz^2)\cap(w^2,\underline{y},yz^2)\cap(x,yz^2)=(w^2,x,y)\cap(w^2,x,z^2)\cap(w^2,y)\cap(x,y)\cap(x,z^2)=(w^2,y)\cap(x,z^2)\cap(x,y)$$ is a reduced primary decomposition, so the associated (minimal) prime ideals are $(y,w),(x,z),(x,y)$.

For intersections, let's consider $(y,w)\cap(x,z)=(xw,zw,xy,yz)$. In $R$ we have $xy=0$, so one can get rid of this.

$Ann_R(x,y)=(z^2w^2)$, $Ann_R(x,z)=(yz)$, and $Ann_R(y,w)=(xw)$.

Comment: I've underlined some elements (until I got bored) in order to make clear the algorithm I use.

Comment: Thanks for displaying that level of detail +1... I'll need a bit of time to let this sink in...

Comment: While thinking about it earlier, I felt like hoping that the generators of the intersection of monomial ideals being the pairwise products was too good to be true, but I've convinced myself now. That's an important lemma to know for sure. I think that essentially describes the steps your taking in the sequence, too.

Comment: In fact they are the lcm of the generators.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is what I should have said...

Comment: Computing the intersection of all the minimal primes that way, it looks like the nilradical must be $(wx, wxz, wyz, yz)=(wx,yz)$ exactly.  But $Ann(x,y)$ is not $(w,y)\cap(x,z)$ because $0\neq wx(x)$, right? Certainly $Ann(x,y)\subseteq (w,y)\cap(x,z)$, though. Oh, maybe you were typing $(w^2,y)\cap(x,z^2)$? That multiplies to zero against $(x,y)$, I believe. I'll have to think about the other two annihilators.

Comment: Do you happen to know if the variety of this coordinate ring has qualities worth noting? How do the geometers describe it with twists/cusps/whatnot?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not very good at geometry, so I can't say anything about this variety. But the coordinate ring is not Cohen-Macaulay having $\dim R=2$ and $\operatorname{depth}R=1$.